# Angular @Input() not updating value is changed in parent component even when using ngOnChanges

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a little problem and I am not sure what the issue is, perhaps someone here can help?

In my Angular App I have a component that contains a child directive that is attached to  form inputs. This child directive takes an `@Input()` which is a string array called `errors`.

So in the parent HTML template we have something like so...

```
<!-- parent-component.component.html file -->
<input type="text" myDirectiveName [errors]="errors">
```

I want it so that when the `errors` sting array value changes this change is detected in the directive. I always thought that `@Inputs()` are treated as Observables so in the parent component I did the following (I have reduced the code for simplicity)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent-component.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    
    // declare the errors string array
    errors = [];

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getErrors();
    }

    getErrors(): void {
        setInterval(() => {
          if(this.errors.length > 3) {
            this.errors.length = 0;
          } else {
            this.errors.push('This is an error');
          }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

I thought this would automatically update in my `@Input` but it does not, even though if I write the errors array to parent interface in the `parent-component.component.html` file using `{{ errors | json }}`  I can see the array increase and shrink over time.

So, I thought I will use `ngOnChanges` within my Directive to capture the changes, here is some simplified code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirectiveName]'
})
export class errorDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {

@Input() errors: string[];

ngOnInit() {
// do stuff...
}

ngOnChanges(simpleChange: any) {
    console.log(simpleChange);
  }
}
```

Using this code I can see the changes being output as the Input is initialized but not when I change the value later in the parent. Is the problem how I am changing my errors array using `setTimeout`? I'm really confused why I can't capture the changes via the Directive `Input()`? If anyone can help me understand what I am doing wrong I would be most appreciative.

Also if my wording is confusing or wrong please add a comment and I shall reword/rework this question.

Comment: You are missing an `@Input()` decorator on `errors` in your component

Comment: You're mutating the `errors` array. Try to update it immutable.

Comment: why are you adding your component to a input tag? <input type="text" myDirectiveName [errors]="errors">. shouldn't it be use like a tag such as <myDirectiveName [errors]="errors"></myDirectiveName> ??

Comment: I have just added an example for you. please take a look if it solves your problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vnbhey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors is an array, which is an object i.e. immutable. for inputs to detect changes in ngonchanges you have to assign a new reference to array. one of the way is to create shallow copy by using spread operator where ever are are adding or removing any value from array.

```
this.errors.push('new error');
this.errors = [...this.errors];
```